# fast way to show pending security updates

Tags: apt

To check pending updates with:

```
apt-get upgrade
```

...takes quite a while.

Is there a faster way to only show pending updates (assuming you have already updated the source list before with apt-get update)

Comment: AFAIK , searching for a fast mirror and then looking after apt-get upgrade would help you.

Comment: Give it the `--dry-run` option?

Comment: Are you looking for [aptdaemon](https://wiki.debian.org/aptdaemon)?

Comment: No, i look for a way to check in milliseconds if there are pending upgrades

Answer (score 1):

You can install `cron-apt` which periodically automates the process to upgrade the Debian system:

```
apt-get install cron-apt
```

By default it **updates the source list** and automatically downloads all new packages. Downloading is not needed in this case, so you disable the download part by removing the download commands:

```
rm /etc/cron-apt/action.d/3-download
```

(In case later you need it: the configuration files are in `/usr/share/doc/cron-apt/examples/`)

This assures that you package list is up-to-date enough. Now you can get the number of packages that would be upgraded with

```
LANG=C apt-get upgrade -s |grep -P '^\d+ upgraded'|cut -d" " -f1
```

Or alternative you can install `apt-show-versions` to use this instead to show the number of packets that have updates:

```
apt-show-versions -b -u|wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is with `apt-show-versions -u`. Shows only installed packages with available updates with current and available version. Use `-b` to show only the package name (suitable for feeding to `apt-get install`).